# Change string records to date type in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have created a table named ticket and in one of the table columns i have stored the dates into 'data' wich are in TEXT format formatted like this '8/1/2014' m-d-Y.
Now i am trying to convert  this columns 'data' to DATE format in MYSQL.
When i change the Column 'data' to Date format are the records seems to change like this '0000-00-00'.
Please help me to change this records without changing the value only the type from TEXT to DATE

Answer (score 0):

```
$select="SELECT * from TableName";
        $select = mysql_query($select);
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($select);

$date = $row['FildName']; 
$convertdate= date('y/m/d ', strtotime($date));
echo $convertdate;
```